# Auto-restarting python script in a screen session via cronjob

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

So I have a raspberry pi which I'm running a blissflixx server on and would like to start it via a cronjob. I know I could set it up with a proper tool like monit, but I don't feel like messing around with .pid files and setting up more config-I just want a cron job to run every 5 minutes checking if blissflixx is running and, if not, restarting it, but no combination seems to make it work. The wrapper script works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/pgrep -f blissflixx.py || /usr/bin/python /home/pi/blissflixx/blissflixx.py --port 8080 --daemon
```

But putting that into my crontab doesn't work:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/blissflixx/start.sh
```

I've tried this with '/bin/bash /home/pi/blissflixx/start.sh' and with various endings of > /dev/null and & at the end of the crontab line, with no success. This exact config works on other devices, I just can't figure out why it doesn't work here. Both the scripts are configured with execute access:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/blissflixx$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi  5521 Jul 19 18:06 blissflixx.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi   125 Aug 17 15:16 start.sh
```

And my cronjobs are definitely running:

```
Aug 17 15:33:01 raspberrypi CRON[14867]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/blissflixx/start.sh)
```

Thoughts, anyone? Again running the start.sh file works fine, it just doesn't work from within crontab...

Comment: Also, this is not in a screen session-I was having issues with that elsewhere when I started writing this post but managed to get that one working-this *should* have been even simpler than that...

Comment: Try running the script in debug mode or redirecting the output to a file so we can see what's happening at runtime